# I have two dates. i want to set another one same as first one by taking time difference

Tags: javascript

```
var d1= new Date();
var d2= new Date('1/23/2017 2:10:23 PM'); // server date
var diff = Math.abs(new Date(d1) - new Date(d2));
```

i want to set **javascript date(d1) same as serverdate (d2)** but there is slight difference in time.so i took differnce and want to add that difference in javascript date.How can i do that?

Comment: If you want to set them the same, why don't you just copy one to the other, why do you need the difference?

Comment: `var d1 = new Date(d2);`

Comment: Why are you converting them both into dates, when they are already dates?

Comment: But i want to set using difference

Answer (score 1):

```js
var d1= new Date();
var d2= new Date('1/23/2017 2:10:23 PM'); // server date
var diff = Math.abs(new Date(d1) - new Date(d2));
var newDate = new Date(d1.getTime() + diff);
console.log(newDate);
```